# Fancybox, getting Fancybox to bind using LIVE() to items being loaded onto the page after load

Tags: binding, fancybox, jquery

I have a page that loads and after it loads, it pulls in a list of LIs to populate a news feed.

```
<li><a href="/url/" class="quickview">quick view</a></li>
<li><a href="/url/" class="quickview">quick view</a></li>
<li><a href="/url/" class="quickview">quick view</a></li>
```

I'm trying to get fancy box to trigger when a user clicks on quick view but haven't had any luck. Any Ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.quickview').fancybox();
});
```

also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.quickview').live('click', function() {
        $(this).fancybox();
    });
});
```

http://fancybox.net/

Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problems is to attach fancybox into AJAX loaded element, right?

I got same problems and I found [this solution](http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/issues/detail?id=18#c15).

I copy paste it here, see the original bug report for more info:

```
$.fn.fancybox = function(options) {

$(this)
  .die('click.fb')
  .live('click.fb', function(e) {       
    $(this).data('fancybox', $.extend({}, options, ($.metadata ? $(this).metadata() : {})))
    e.preventDefault();
    [...]
```

Credit goes to [jeff.gran](http://code.google.com/u/jeff.gran/).

Comment: That solution broke regular photo galleries for me, but I was able to fix it as I commented here: http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/issues/detail?id=18#c47

Answer (score 30):

Old question, but might be useful for future searchers.

My preferred solution is to fire fancybox manually from within the live event, eg:

```
$('.lightbox').live('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.fancybox({
        height: '100%',
        href: $this.attr('href'),
        type: 'iframe',
        width: '100%'
    });
    return false;
});
```

EDIT: From jQuery 1.7 live() is deprecated and on() should be used instead. See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more info.

Comment: 100% prefer this solutions thanks for taking the time to provide it.

Comment: Can you use 'gallery' feature this way? (next/prev links)

Comment: This was by far my prefered solution and it works mighty well... good job

Comment: +1... dude this is a great solution... you saved a lot of my time, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it was helpful... but I think in most instances you could simplify it to be more like this: `$('.lightbox').live('click', function() { $.fancybox({ href: $(this).attr('href') }) });`.  (Unless you really needed those extra params when calling the lightbox function.

Comment: Note this important bit: `href: $this.attr('href')`.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I was having issues using `on` and realised I had to call the static parent to the ajax content as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9344454/436014)

Answer (score 23):

this should work after every ajax request

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() { 
    $("#whatever").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. live() is a good thing to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Since `.on` is now recommended over `.live`, and after reading over the [documentation on delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/), here's a solution I came up with (assuming your elements have a class of 'trigger-modal'):

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger-modal', function() {
  // remove the class to ensure this will only run once
  $(this).removeClass('trigger-modal');
  // now attach fancybox and click to open it
  $(this).fancybox().click();
  // prevent default action
  return false;
});
```

Comment: or even just `$(document).on('click', '.trigger-modal', function() { $.fancybox(); return false; });`

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto), the call to `fancybox()` simple attaches the plugin to the selected element. Calling `fancybox` on a `click` event won't open anything.

I think you just need to add

```
$(li_element_that_you_create).fancybox();
```

to the code that creates the new `LI` elements in your list

**EDIT**

If you're using `load`, then you would do something like:

```
$('#ul_id_goes_here').load('source/of/news.feed', function() {
  $('.quickview').fancybox();
});
```

Comment: I'm not following, I'm using JQUERY load?