# jQuery append html

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, fancybox, livequery

```
jQuery('.block').append(html);
```

**How do I run livequery on this append?**

I've http://fancybox.net on my image, trying to execute it for appended html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, to aim your images :

```
$('.block').find('#myImages img').fancybox();
```

If that doesn't work, you can look the accepted answer here : [Fancybox, getting Fancybox to bind using LIVE() to items being loaded onto the page after load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532070/fancybox-getting-fancybox-to-bind-using-live-to-items-being-loaded-onto-the-pa)

Comment: It's alive, it's moving, it's alive, it's alive, it's alive, it's alive, IT'S ALIVE!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you did this on page load:

```
$('#myImages').fancybox();
```

And doing the following appended more `#myImages`:

```
$('.block').append(html);
```

Then you can bind `.fancybox()` to just those elements:

```
$('.block').find('#myImages').fancybox();
```