# Fancybox box won't popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, modal-dialog

I've successfully created some test pages using the Fancybox library.

However, when I try to integrate the library into the main site, instead of opening up an image in the modal window, it opens it in a separate tab/window/page.

The successful empty test is here: http://www.halal-helvetica.ch/kash.html

To get to the one that doesn't work, you need to go to: http://www.halal-helvetica.ch/index2.php, then search for Bern. Then click on the icon for a restaurant, and then click on the small grey square in the info area on the left of the screen. When you click that, you'll see that it opens up a large grey square in a new page instead of in the modal window.

I hope i've been specific enough.

Thanks
Kash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind the Fancybox to `a#single_image` in `base2.js`, you're doing it on page load when there aren't any occurances of it. Later the element is created when a marker is clicked, so nothing is bound. The `$.live()` function of jQuery will bind on page load, but also bind any future matches through AJAX calls or whatever. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532070/fancybox-getting-fancybox-to-bind-using-live-to-items-being-loaded-onto-the-pa) should help get `$.live()` working with Fancybox.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the link Tak, and also explaining what the problem was. I simply replaced:

`$(document).ready(function() {`

with" 

`$(document).ajaxStop(function() {`