# Fancybox plugin: rewrite href option on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have got some links like:

```
<a href='http://mysite.com/comment/123/edit' class='fancybox'>Edit comment</a>
```

And Fancybox plugin:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

When I click on the link I'll see some page from `http://mysite.com/comment/123/edit`, but I want to see `http://mysite.com/comment/123/edit.js`.

I know there is `href` option, but how can I rewrite it to append `.js` at the end of my original href.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `href` attribute as you apply fancybox:

```
$(".fancybox").attr('href', function() { return $(this).attr('href') + '.js'; }).fancybox();
```

If you don't want to change the attribute (keep the link the same), but want it applied for fancybox only, use the `href` option you mentioned:

```
$(".fancybox").each(function () {
    $(this).fancybox({ href: $(this).attr('href') + '.js' });
});
```

Comment: Yeap, that's it. Little fix `$(this).fancybox({ href: $(this).attr('href') + '.js', ajax: {dataType: "html"} });` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a problem: some `.fancybox` elements appends to the page dynamically after your function is triggered. Is there any way to change `href` option straight in fancybox? so I don't need to watch if there are new `.fancybox` elements on the page

Comment: Don't you already need to rebind fancybox to those new elements? Check this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532070/fancybox-getting-fancybox-to-bind-using-live-to-items-being-loaded-onto-the-pa